# The ultimate search with query strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, query-string

This is rather a long question, so please bear with me

We've got an application that run on **Express**, **Mongo**, **React** and **Redux**. I've written middle-wares and route-handlers that handle the incoming request by getting the query string.

Here's the code for the backend:

1. **Backend: Node, Express**

**Peopleservices.js**

```
const people = require("../models/Person");

// creating the filter function
const findBy = filter => {
  // loop on filter props
  const query = {};

  for (prop in filter) {
    // if the prop contains gt or lt we should change it to mongo style query
    if (prop.includes("_")) {
      let finalQuery = {};
      let parts = prop.split("_");
      query[parts[0]] = parts[1];
      finalQuery[`$${parts[1]}`] = filter[prop];
      query[parts[0]] = finalQuery;
    } else {
      // if the prop does not containg gt or lt, just return the same query
      query[prop] = filter[prop];
    }
  }
  // finally, return the query
  return people.find(query);
};

module.exports = {
  findBy
};
```

This is where we get the query string and convert to mongo understandable query.

**PeopleRouters.js**

```
module.exports = app => {
  // calling services
  const service = require("../services/peopleService");

  // Route to handle everyone
  app.get(["/everyone"], async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const filter = req.query || {};
      const all = await service.findBy(filter);
      res.status(200).send(all);
    } catch (ex) {
      next(ex);
    }
  });
};
```

Then we call the router with the right query

**2. Frontend: React, Redux**

We will make the query string by the user interaction, there are three input fields namely **Name** , **Gender**, and **Age**. Based on the given combination we create the ultimate query string to be sent to the server. This is done this way:

**The form to capture data from user:**

**App.js**

```
render() {
    // the form, ideally could have it's own component
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <div className="row" />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="ui two column centered grid">
            <div className="column">
              <div className="ui form">
                <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="field">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="field">
                    <select
                      name="age"
                      value={this.state.age}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    >
                      <option value="">Select Age Range</option>
                      <option value="_gte=20">Above 20</option>
                      <option value="_lt=20">Below 20</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="field">
                    <select
                      className="ui fluid dropdown"
                      name="gender"
                      value={this.state.gender}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    >
                      <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                      <option value="female">Female</option>
                      <option value="male">Male</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="ui buttons">
                    <button type="submit" className="ui positive button active">
                      Search
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="ui link cards">{this.renderContent()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Once done, receive the elements, handle the request to be sent to our action creator on the **Redux** side of the app:

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  // submitting the form
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.fetchPeople(this.state.name, this.state.age, this.state.gender);
  };
```

Once we've got all the user data stored in state, we pass it to our action creator:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_PEOPLE } from "./types";

export const fetchPeople = (...args) => async dispatch => {
  // launching the default state
  if (!args[0] && !args[1] && !args[2]) {
    const response = await axios.get(`/everyone`);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: response });
  }
  // if the name is empty, we will run the query for the gender and age
  else if (!args[0] && args[1] && args[2]) {
    console.log("we here?");
    const response = await axios.get(
      `/everyone?age${args[1]}&gender=${args[2]}`
    );
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: response });
  } else {
    // populating with user's input
    const response = await axios.get(
      `/everyone?name=${args[0]}&age${args[1]}&gender=${args[2]}`
    );
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: response });
  }
};
```

Action creator makes the request using **Axios** and the results appear. But as you can see, I could only do a little bit of **if and else** to get only a few combinations covered. Thus, i'm looking for a better way of doing this.

**What I've tried?**

- I've tried refactoring filter and going query.params way on the server side
- I've forced user to input all the fields ( the easy case )
- I've made a wizard form, collected all the data and sent out the results
- I've written a code for dissecting the received state and created the query string based on the length

Although, the code is currently okay, and many applications such as Jira have faced the same issue, and simplified the process by forcing a category at first! I insist on coming up with a cool algorithm that does the magic!

My dear friend engineers, wise people, illuminate me on this matter! I really don't like those **if and elses**! those are sins!

Comment: There's _a lot_ here. I think it would help if you could tighten the focus on this and remove some of the code that doesn't add to the question. If I understand correctly: you're asking about how to deal with an arbitrary amount of positional arguments passed to `fetchPeople`. It could, in theory, get `['name', '', 'gender']` or `['', 'age', 'gender']` or any combination of the three values. And you need to map it to named key/value pairs to use for an HTTP request?

Comment: You're right, there's a lot to it! I just wanted it to be as comprehensive as possible.. You're quite there. The issues here is to try and generate the query string based on user input, for example if the user leaves the 'name' empty and fills in 'age' and 'gender' our query string is like this -> everyone?name=&age_gt=20&gender=male! and so on so forth for other cases! you see, with this query string we cannot get any sensible results from the server, and that is the issue here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it this way:-

```
//Pass object with keys and values from form values as arguments

this.props.fetchPeople({
  name: this.state.name,
  age: this.state.age,
  gender: this.state.gender
});



 // or more flexible approach will be to spread user input values

this.props.fetchPeople({...this.state});



// Make a genQueryString function
 const genQueryString = (args={}) => {
    let queryString = "";
    Object.keys(args).forEach((key) => {
      if(args[key]) {
        if(key === "age") {
          queryString+= `${key}${args[key]}&`;
        } else {
          queryString+= `${key}=${args[key]}&`
        }
      }
    });
    return queryString;
}

export const fetchPeople = (args) => async dispatch => {


  const response = await axios.get(
    `/everyone?${genQueryString(args)}`
  );

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_PEOPLE, payload: response });
  }
};
```

Or you can also use a npm library like qs for generating query string from arguments which will provide more methods:-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

Comment: mate! I didn't want to downgrade the answer but your concatenating an object to a string, that will make a request like this -> "http://localhost:3000/everyone?0=[object%20Object]&"

Comment: Have you tried the solution? It won’t do what you are saying. You need to receive the first argument in fetch people which will be an object. Don’t spread args in fetch people.

Comment: Yes, we get typeError, because we Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Object.keys(args).forEach(key => {

Comment: Are you calling fetch people with an object as I mentioned above? It seems you are not passing an object.

Comment: I have ran the same code and I didn’t get any error. There is something wrong. Can you show your code?

Comment: I've copied your genQueryString into the top of my action creator file... Are you running on React?

Comment: It doesn’t have to do anything with react. Its a simple function that will convert an object with keys and values to a query string. Put a console log an check what gets passed as args in genQueryString function.

Comment: Okay, here's a thing, I run the action creator once in ComponentdidMount() so this will definitely run at least once! and that's were well get the null

Comment: Okay. So use default param. I have updated the genQueryString function.

Comment: Alright, you've neglect one part of my code, we do have a drop down, in which user choses above or below 20, that has to be converted later into mogno language right? So the value of the option we get from the dropdown should be age_gt=20 or age_lt=20... having that said, your code, creates query string like this -> everyone?age=_gte=20... and that does not resolve in the server...
If you check my serverside code, I convert age_gt=20 into age: { $gt: 20}

Comment: See. If you want to map every mongodb query, you will need a more complex function. Now, I myself would want such thing but it will be too complex will require a lot of work. And most of this stuff should be handled by server alone. You can still do nested queries with dot notation using qs library but many cases won’t be handled that easily. Greater than case can be handled with my approach.

Comment: Not every mongoDB query! I just have to handle this age_gt=20 and age_lt=20 thing! just the age range and this is a magic already!

Comment: Did you look into qs libraby?

Comment: Yes i have, it's verbose for this specific case, everything is already there! it's more of a programming issue. I can redesign the whole thing with query.params and it would be a piece of cake! but I want it done this way... I've written a function similar to yours before! I'm working towards it... I think it's possible and we are close..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192852/discussion-between-ceenikc-and-neophyte-polyhistor).